# Workbook.save not working VBA EXcel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello my code is supposed to add another worksheet, then save the file and close it. my problem is with the save. It just doesnt save.

I did a

```
Do while (Not workbook.saved)
Workbook.save
Loop
```

And it went to a infinite loop -__-
The workbook is a CSV file, being accessed via VBA. and returns 2 dialogue boxes which is turned off via

```
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Workbook`.

Comment: I know it's this workbook. I made an object and made it workbook

Comment: what alerts come up when .displayalerts is turned on?

Comment: Guys I thank everyone for the help. I figured it out eventually after few hours of intensive debugging. It's actually saving and closing properly. It's just that it's doing it too fast the sheet that I added haven't been added and it's closing already. With this I end this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file cannot contain multiple worksheets. Use SaveAs method instead of Save.

Comment: I actually already have an existing CSV file. Save works, I just have to copy the sheet after the original sheet of the csv.

Answer (score 0):

instead of **Workbook.save**, you might want to use **Workbook.Close True**